# Pimcore While localization of a field move existing data to localized en(english) language

Tags: localization, pimcore

I have a existing project developed on pimcore 3. I am facing a challenge while localizing the existing fields of a class, as on moving a field into the localized field container means the loss of data from the field in all objects using this class. I don't want to loss that data and instead wanted  that data to be moved to english language of that localizedfield container.

Let's say I have a class "test"  with below fields:

- Name  (text)
- Desc   (textarea)
- Type   (text)
- Category (object)

Let's say now I want to localize below 3 fields for English , French and German.

- Name  (text)
- Desc   (textarea)
- Category (object)

But I don't want my existing data to be lost, instead I want the english language of field of that localization to be filled up with existing data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not completely straightforward. In the most simple case you should write two simple scripts.

Follow this workflow:

- duplicate the three fields, eg. NameTemp, DescTemp and CategoryTemp
- create a script that copies the data from Name to NameTemp, from Desc
  to DescTemp and Category to CategoryTemp

After you copied do this:

- move fields Name, Desc, Category into localized field - (your data is
  still left in NameTemp, DescTemp and CategoryTemp)
- now create a new script which copies the data from NameTemp to Name,      DescTemp to Desc and CategoryTemp to Category

Sample script (NOT TESTED):

```php
// First run copyValueFromFieldsToTempFieldsAction(), 
// then move the fields into localized field,
// afterwards run copyValueFromTempFieldsToFieldsAction()
// in the end remove temp fields
public function copyValueFromFieldsToTempFieldsAction(){
  $this->disableViewAutoRender();

  $objectList = new \Pimcore\Model\YourObject\Listing();
  //$object_list->setObjectTypes(array(Object_Abstract::OBJECT_TYPE_VARIANT));

  /* @var $object Object_PrdktResetkeNaZalogi */
  foreach($objectList as $object){
      $object->setNameTemp($object->getName());
      $object->setDescTemp($object->getTemp());
      $object->setCategoryTemp($object->getCategory());

      $object->save();
  }
}

public function copyValueFromTempFieldsToFieldsAction(){
  $this->disableViewAutoRender();

  $objectList = new \Pimcore\Model\YourObject\Listing();
  //$object_list->setObjectTypes(array(Object_Abstract::OBJECT_TYPE_VARIANT));

  /* @var $object Object_PrdktResetkeNaZalogi */
  foreach($objectList as $object){
      $object->setTemp($object->getNameTemp());
      $object->setDesc($object->getTemp());
      $object->setCategory($object->getCategorTemp());

      $object->save();
  }
}
```